# gps app for android useing shapefiles

Tags: android, gps, kml, arcgis

I'm very new to android development.  I would like to make a android app for my senior project.  The idea for the project is this: build an app that will show one's location on a map be it on a road or path.  So it looks like using google maps and the Locator class this can be done.  But here is the thing I have shapefile for the path system in esir format.  It looks like one could export this from ArcGIS as a KML file, and then overlay it on top of the google map.  Now of course I would like the GPS location displayed to the user to "snap" to the nearest path if it is in say 15m of the path to help hide the inaccuracies in the GPS.  I would also like to be able to place notification icons on the map, e.g. path condition, that could be updated from time to time.  I do also have shapefiles for the roads, streams, lakes, etc. for the area, so I could just use them instead of google maps.  Is using google map and overlaying the KML file the best way to do this?  Does this sound like a doable project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of caurse it's a doable project .there are many solutions for this kinde of projects for your base map you can use google map , openstreetmap ,Bingmap (personnaly i prefer openstreetmap ),open layer  ..... , After that you can choose between google map api or Arcgis Api (personnaly i think that arcgis api is more Professional including all services of a GIS ) ... ,for Gps there ara many solutions one of theme is to update your Gpx file and project it like a  graphic layer in you app .